# How to Get comments in .net compiled files?

Tags: vb.net

How can read or retrieve comments in .net compiled files
for example

```
    'get current os info
   Public Property CheckOs As String 'checking operating system
```

we can read the property with ilspy or reflector but where we find the comments
{" 'get current os info,  'checking operating system"}
is that stored in resources or any other places ?.

Comment: No, they're thrown out by the compiler during compilation. "XML documentation", like the one found in C# (don't know if VB has something similar but I bet it does) can be configured to be placed in a .xml file beside the .dll, but nothing is embedded into the .dll itself.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/documenting-your-code-with-xml

Comment: Comments are for making the code readable. DLLs are not for readability by humans, but by processors and processors don't need comments, so DLLs don't have comments

Comment: That wont get picked up in xml anyways, it is not valid. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-xml-tags-for-documentation-comments

Comment: i write some information in comments about the variable every time in codes, so i bit confused about that finally i will keep this way ...thnks to all ....

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET, you can add comments above a function, property, or whatever starting with `'''`.  Visual Studio will automatically provide a template XML comment block that looks like this:

```
''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <param name="emailAddress"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
```

I just copied and pasted that from a function that has one parameter called emailAddress - YMMV.
If you fill this in (at least the summary part), then Visual Studio's Intellisense will give you a tool-tip with the function help whenever you hover over a call to that function start typing a call to it.

Also, the compiler will write out an XML file containing the XML comment data along with your DLL.  If you keep that XML with the DLL when you reference it in another project, then the programmer using it will get the Intellisense too.

Note, this same feature exists for C#, but uses `///` instead of `'''`